# javascript replace all with case insensitive and keeping correct case in original string

Tags: javascript

My problem is i want to do something like this:

`Javascript vaja => <b>Ja</b>vascript va<b>ja</b>`
i.e i have a query string(ja) and i want to replace all the occurances(case insensitive) of that query string in a bigger string (Javascript vaja).

The closest solution i have right now is:

`"Javascript vaja".replace(/ja/gi, '<b>ja</b>');`

which gives me:

`"<b>ja</b>vascript va<b>ja</b>"`

but what i need is:

`Javascript vaja => <b>Ja</b>vascript va<b>ja</b>`

one solution that i have in mind is to keep the indexes of upcase letters before replacement and then re replace them. But that is way too hacky.
I am pretty sure i am not the first one trying this and pretty sure there is some elegant and simpler solution hidden somewhere.

Comment: Why not just execute two case-sensitive replace() calls?

Comment: i am not pretty sure what your solution is but i want to handle cases
like :
`Bavascript vaba => <b>B</b>avascript va<b>b</b>a` and replacing iteratively will crete problems in this case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply use a capturing group:

```
"Javascript vaja".replace(/(ja)/gi, '<b>$1</b>');
```

### [See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Awz/)

**Edit:** Read more about capturing groups [**here.**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: perfecttttt.. thanks a lot . works like charm.(i can only accept answer after 5 minutes SO says so :))

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input  = "Javascript vaja";
const output = input.replace(/ja/gi, '<b>$&</b>');

console.log(output); // <b>Ja</b>vascript va<b>ja</b>
```