# HTML DOM manipulation : properly replace tag by heading tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I want to replace some tag-inside-a-paragraph-tag by a heading-tag-enclosed-by-a-paragraph tag. This would result in proper W3C coding, but it seems that jQuery is not able to manipulate the DOM in the right way!? I tried several ways of (jQuery) coding, but i can't get it to work ..

Original code:

```
<p>some text <span>replace me</span> some more text</p>
```

Desired code:

```
<p>some text</p><h2>my heading</h2><p>some more text</p>
```

Resulting code by jQuery replaceWith():

```
<p>some text<p></p><h2>my heading</h2><p></p>some more text</p>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/foleox/J43rN/4/
In this demo, look at "make H2 custom" : i expect this to work (it's a logical replace statement), but it results in adding two empty p-tags .. The other 2 functions ("make code" and "make H2 pure") are for reference.

Officially the W3C definition states that any heading tag should not be inside a paragraph tag - you can check this by doing a W3C validation. So, why does jQuery add empty paragraph tags? Does anybody know a way to achieve this? Am i mistaken somehow?

Comment: Because you're telling it to. You're using the replaceWith function on a child, so how is it supposed to tell you want to close the parent tag?

Comment: The browser closes the paragraph as you can't have a H2 inside a paragraph.

Comment: computer are stupid... they do what we tell them to do. and you are saying to put that h2-h.. there

Comment: I just updated the example JSFiddle code a little bit .. I tell jQuery to replace `<span>replace me</span>` by `</p><h2>my heading</h2><p>` so the surrounding p-tags should be closed / opened, right?

Comment: Look for my solution below for a case-insensitive solution that will also handle multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with this code. However it's pretty ugly:

```
$('.replaceMe').each(function() {

    var $parent = $(this).parent(),
        $h2 = $(this).before('$sep$').wrap('<h2>').parent().insertAfter($parent);

    var split = $parent.html().split('$sep$');

    $parent.before('<p>' + split[0] + '</p>');
    $h2.after('<p>' + split[1] + '</p>');

    $parent.remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J43rN/5/

Comment: Your solution works, among other coding answers which don't .. It's a bit ugly indeed, but i guess there are many ways to (quickly) achieve a goal .. I used your code to come up with my definite solution, using your split/after/before idea and not rewriting the parent content, because this (always) generates the unwanted empty p-tags. See http://jsfiddle.net/foleox/J43rN : it holds a general replace function which can also do other replacements alike.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), you will find:

> When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or
>   quick-closing) — `$("<img />")` or `$("<img>")`, `$("<a></a>")` or `$("<a>")`
>   — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript
>   createElement() function.

So that is exactly what it is doing. And as I said in my comment, you can't change a parent node from a child node, you're altering the DOM here, not HTML code. So you'll need to either use `replaceWith` on the parent node and replace everything or use something like `remove` and `append` to split it up in multiple elements which you append after each other.

Comment: OK, you're right .. i used something like this in my definite code : see my accepted solution of @dfsq.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var temp = "<p>some text <span>replace me</span> some more text</p>";
temp.replace(/(\<span\>replace me\<\/span\>)/gi, '</p><h2>my heading</h2><p>');
```

This will do a case insensitive replace for multiple occurences as well.

Read more about capturing groups [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Original credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161919/javascript-replace-all-with-case-insensitive-and-keeping-correct-case-in-origina) question!

Comment: OK, this is the way the replace function works .. it can be useful, but i'm looking for a way to handle DOM elements, not only strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I have updated the http://jsfiddle.net/J43rN/6/ example by the below java script function please check I hope it will work for you

```
function fnMakeCode() {
    $('#myP #replaceMe').html("<code id='replaceMe'>My Code</code>");
}
function fnMakeH2pure() {
    $('#myP #replaceMe').html("<h2 id='replaceMe'>My H2 pure</h2>");
}
function fnMakeH2custom() {
     $('#replaceMe').html("<p></p>").html("<h2>My H2 custom</h2>");
}
```

Comment: i see you changed the fnMakeH2custom() at bit, but this does not work .. i tried this at first .. the result is that some empty p-tags are added, as i stated.

Comment: Can you please paste your java-script function and html so I can check if possible?

Comment: please use the edited code I have tested it should work
here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/J43rN/6/

Comment: :@SystematixInfotech : no, the result of this JSfiddle seems OK at first glance, but it's not what i want to achieve. Read my question and look into the DOM of your result.